# register audiovideoplayback.dll assembly without set up direct x dependences

Tags: c#

I Make windows application with vb.net and use audiovideoplayback.dll , to play videos , and when make set up with set up factory and run application in another pc i got this error

```
could not load file or assembly microsoft directx audiovideoplayback not install directx
```

i solve the problem with set up directx_Jun2010_redist.exe 
from this link
https://download.microsoft.com/download/8/4/A/84A35BF1-DAFE-4AE8-82AF-AD2AE20B6B14/directx_Jun2010_redist.exe
but the size of it is very large (more than 100 mb)
I want to find way to avoid install this exe
I found the extracted version of exe but has a lot of folders and files and i can not specify what is the key files that responsible for register assembly of audiovideoplayback.dll i need put it on my set up package with set up factory ,any ideas guys , thanks

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow, This is just a message I send to new members to help things along a bit. The learning curve for a new user isn't steep as such, but finding out how to use stack isn't always obvious. Please do take a few minutes and have a look here **[ask]** and it's also important to look here .. **[mcve]** .. **Also, if an answer is valid for you, click on the tick to the left of the answer so that the question is marked as answered** and this makes sure that the person who posted it gets reputation. Cheers.

Comment: Also please only add one language tab - the one you are using - a lot of users ignore posts that contain tags they don't specialize in. Thanks